# Search for value in XML and copy element into another file

Tags: xml

We have a lot of xml files with appr. 500000 lines, which we use for a migration. Now some of the already loaded object went wrong and I have to create an extra xml files. I need to search for one value between `Alias>XXX</Alias>` and need to copy the elements from `<File> to </File>` into a new xml file. I need to search for 800 Alias entries in 100 xml files.

I am not a programmer and tried to solve it with my tools.

Example xml

```
<Root>
<File>
 <OriginalFile>
  <TheDocFile>B-ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010-C.tif</TheDocFile>
  <TheDocFile>B-ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010-C.dwg</TheDocFile>
 </OriginalFile>
 <AgfaTitelhoek>
  <Alias>ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010</Alias>
  <Basiskalk>STXX520</Basiskalk>
  <Uitvoerder></Uitvoerder>
  <Tek.Naam>QualiTek</Tek.Naam>
  <Tek.Tel></Tek.Tel>
  <Tek.Datum>20170505</Tek.Datum>
  <Nag.Naam>DE WAELE D.</Nag.Naam>
  <Nag.Tel>7823</Nag.Tel>
  <Nag.Datum>20180416</Nag.Datum>
  <Goedk.Naam></Goedk.Naam>
  <Goedk.Tel></Goedk.Tel>
  <Goedk.Datum></Goedk.Datum>
  <Titellijn1>BEVEILIGINGSLIJST</Titellijn1>
  <Titellijn2>VERDEELBORD 20.801</Titellijn2>
  <VestGebouw>0531</VestGebouw>
  <Vestiging>05</Vestiging>
  <Gebouw>31</Gebouw>
  <PRCCode>ELD1</PRCCode>
  <PRECode>HS5E</PRECode>
  <FieGrpCode>----</FieGrpCode>
  <BwdCode>----</BwdCode>
  <Verdieping>20</Verdieping>
  <ZLS>L29</ZLS>
  <PVB>801</PVB>
  <Soort>KT</Soort>
  <Volgnummer>7010</Volgnummer>
  <Bordnummer></Bordnummer>
  <Veldnummer></Veldnummer>
  <Plannummer></Plannummer>
  <Uitgave>C</Uitgave>
  <Lastenboeknr></Lastenboeknr>
  <Ontstaan></Ontstaan>
  <Landcode>BE</Landcode>
  <StatusPlan>As Built</StatusPlan>
  <Vakgebied>X</Vakgebied>
  <Kaft></Kaft>
  <UitgelAan></UitgelAan>
  <PageState>GeRegistreerd</PageState>
  <ReservedBy>*</ReservedBy>
  <KBL>B</KBL>
  <PGName>B-ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010</PGName>
  <PRName>B-ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010-C</PRName>
 </AgfaTitelhoek>
</File>
<File>
 <OriginalFile>
  <TheDocFile>B-EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001-O.tif</TheDocFile>
  <TheDocFile>B-EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001-O.dwg</TheDocFile>
 </OriginalFile>
 <AgfaTitelhoek>
  <Alias>EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001</Alias>
  <Basiskalk>STXX660</Basiskalk>
  <Uitvoerder></Uitvoerder>
  <Tek.Naam>QualiTek</Tek.Naam>
  <Tek.Tel></Tek.Tel>
  <Tek.Datum>19990823</Tek.Datum>
  <Nag.Naam>DE WAELE D.</Nag.Naam>
  <Nag.Tel>7823</Nag.Tel>
  <Nag.Datum>20180416</Nag.Datum>
  <Goedk.Naam></Goedk.Naam>
  <Goedk.Tel></Goedk.Tel>
  <Goedk.Datum></Goedk.Datum>
  <Titellijn1>VOORAANZICHT</Titellijn1>
  <Titellijn2>SCHAKELBORD 20.145</Titellijn2>
  <VestGebouw>0531</VestGebouw>
  <Vestiging>05</Vestiging>
  <Gebouw>31</Gebouw>
  <PRCCode>EMG1</PRCCode>
  <PRECode>M037</PRECode>
  <FieGrpCode>----</FieGrpCode>
  <BwdCode>----</BwdCode>
  <Verdieping>20</Verdieping>
  <ZLS>---</ZLS>
  <PVB>145</PVB>
  <Soort>KT</Soort>
  <Volgnummer>2001</Volgnummer>
  <Bordnummer></Bordnummer>
  <Veldnummer></Veldnummer>
  <Plannummer></Plannummer>
  <Uitgave>O</Uitgave>
  <Lastenboeknr></Lastenboeknr>
  <Ontstaan></Ontstaan>
  <Landcode>BE</Landcode>
  <StatusPlan>As Built</StatusPlan>
  <Vakgebied>X</Vakgebied>
  <Kaft>M037.B.03</Kaft>
  <UitgelAan></UitgelAan>
  <PageState>GeRegistreerd</PageState>
  <ReservedBy>*</ReservedBy>
  <KBL>B</KBL>
  <PGName>B-EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001</PGName>
  <PRName>B-EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001-O</PRName>
 </AgfaTitelhoek>
</File>
</Root>
```

I need to search in this case for ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010 and copy all between `<File> to /File>`.
I know all the 800 alias numbers. I cannot run the code 800 times.
Search string is like this

1. ELD1-0531-HS5E-20801KT7010
2. ENR2-0504-0000-02901KT4011
3. Z080-0535-MANU-00116VT6608
4. .
5. .
6. .

If you look at `<TheDocFile>B-EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001-O.tif</TheDocFile>`
there is also a versioning involved. Here we have O (alphabetic sequence).
I have not the info how much versions are behind each number, so sorting afterwards in the xml is a must.

It would be nice if the 800 alias numbers can be somehow put in a txt file as input for the code.

Source:
- Lot of xml files in one folder
- TXT file with around 800 lines as search criteria

Search criteria:
- Search for `<Alias>XXX</Alias>`
- If search criteria  is found copy the whole element from `<File> to /File>`

Result should be
- XML file with all search results - `<File> to /File>`

May be you have also a solution for the sorting, sorting should be done with field `<TheDocFile>B-EMG1-0531-M037-20145KT2001-O.tif</TheDocFile>`. Here there is O the version.

Hope this is not to difficult.
Thx in advance.

If you need more info please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: First, include code as text in a code section and not as image. Second, the tool of your choice should be XSLT. Your problem could probably be solved with version 1.0, so that shouldn't be a problem. But a [mcve]  is needed nevertheless. So a clear definition of what you have as input and want as output is indispensable.

Comment: BTW in your code picture there is no value `ELA1-0512-0000-00101VT1050`. So your question is unclear by now.

Comment: Thx for your comment, edit done. Hope its more clear now. I will have a look at the XSLT.

Comment: Your question is clearer by now. But you did not exhibit any attempt of solving it on your own. Unfortunately (for you) StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. A serious amount of time would have to be invested in solving your problem. Without (a respectable amount of) payment, this is too much work for an SO answer.

Comment: You are right. But your tip to go for XSLT is for the moment enough for me. I will try it out, thx